# How should I set the background colour of an `<iron-overlay-backdrop>`

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element that I want to use when I am waiting for ajax requests to complete.  It consists of a `<paper-spinner>`, but it also has the `Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior` .behavior. It is driven by a `waiting` property, on which I have an observer, so when it's set, the overlay opens.

Operationally this is working fine.  Just the background color is wrong for my site.

I am attempting to style the overlay as per the docs with the following in my template

```
<style >
  :host{
    --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: #fff;
  }
</style>
```

But all I get is the default style of black, rather than the white I am attempting to set.

How should I set the style so that I get a semi transparent white, rather than the semi transparent black that I am getting at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing with [`iron-overlay-backdrop`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior?active=iron-overlay-backdrop) is that it's a singleton that's not appended to an element's local DOM but to the main DOM.

So to set its custom css properties or mixins you should do it on a `custom-style` tha applies to the main DOM like this:

```
<style is="custom-style">
iron-overlay-backdrop {
  --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: #fff;
  --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.9;
}
</style>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLatqmeL/) showing it in action

Comment: As Alan writes it's important to add this css property to the main CSS and not the one in your custom module (at least for Polymer 1)